# Prove that $(1 + x)(1 + y) < (1 - x)(1 - y)(1 + z)$?

Tags: inequality

If $3x + 3y < z \leq 1$ and $0 < x, y < \frac{1}{3}$, how to prove that $(1 + x)(1 + y) < (1 - x)(1 - y)(1 + z)$?

Attempt: Using $(1 + a)(1 - a) \leq 1$, when $a \in [-1, 1]$,
we can see that $(1 - x)(1 - y)(1 + z) < (1 - x)(1 - y)/(1 - z)$.
Not sure to how to compute a lower bound on $(1 - x)(1 - y)(1 + z)$.

Comment: Using $(1 + a)(1 - a) \leq 1$, when $a \in [-1, 1]$, 
we can see that $(1 - x)(1 - y)(1 + z) < (1 - x)(1 - y)/(1 - z)$. 
Not sure to how to compute a lower bound on $(1 - x)(1 - y)(1 + z)$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should put your attempt/thoughts in the body of the question via editting, not in a comment.  As it is it looks like a problem statement question with no work, which tends to be dowvoted/closed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We want to show that
$$
(1 + x)(1 + y) < (1-x)(1-y) (1+z)
$$
This is equivalent to showing that
$$
\begin{align}
(1 + x)(1 + y) &< (1-x)(1-y) (1+z)  + (1+x)(1+y) (1+z) - (1+x)(1+y) (1+z) \\
\iff
\\
0 &< z(1+x)(1+y) + (1-x)(1-y) (1+z) - (1+x)(1+y) (1+z) \\
&=z(1+x)(1+y) + [(1-x)(1-y) - (1+x)(1+y)] (1+z) \\
&= z(1+x)(1+y) + 2[1 - x - y] (1+z)
\end{align}
$$
Since all the terms of the above are positive for admissible $x,y,z$ the claim follows.